# @PostConstruct method init() is never invoked on a ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, postconstruct

I'm still a beginner at JSF programming and I'm trying to do a little example to understand how it works.
I'm facing the problem where the @PostConstruct method of a managed bean is never invoked (the instanciations in it are never made, and the println in it doesn't show a thing)
I tried all sorts of managed beans (Session, Request...), but there is always the same problem !

My managed bean :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "helloWorldMBean")
@SessionScoped
public class HelloWorldMBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private PortletRequest request;
private String nom;
private String prenom;
private String complement;
private BigDecimal age;
private String year;

/* getters and setters */

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    System.out.println("Hi !");
    if (request == null) {
        request = (PortletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    }
    complement = "...";
    nom = "Init";
    System.out.println("Comp : " + complement);
}
```

Comment: I assume you are referencing the bean using EL in a jsf page?

Comment: Hi kharyam, yes I use it in a jsf page as follows :

    <h:outputText value="You are #{helloWorldMBean.nom} #{helloWorldMBean.prenom}....

Comment: I do not know anything about portlet, but beside this, I cannot spot any error. What JSF version are you using? what machine is your code running on? what do your imports look like? What does your faces-config look like? How do you try to access the webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments. 
I just found out what was missing on my project : it's the jboss-deployment-structure.xml !
I added it with the dependencies and it worked, though I don't understand it yet.